# How to set env variable and start a process in C?

Tags: c, process, environment-variables, c89

How to set an environment variable and start a process in ANSI C for Windows? If possible I want to avoid using any Windows API for this.

Comment: What do you eam you want to "avoid using any windows API"? Starting processes requires using an API of *some* kind... are you saying you only want to use standard C?

Comment: yes , standard ANSI C. Want to avoid ShellExecute or something

Comment: It hasn't been _ANSI_ C for a long time, ANSI just rubber stamps ISO nowadays :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming portability is your reason for specifying ANSI C, you can do exactly what you want with the POSIX function `_execve`:

- [MSDN CRT Reference: _execve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyw61wtd(v=VS.80).aspx)

This is a portable function that spawns a new child process and allows you to supply an array of environment settings.

Answer (score 3):

In pure ANSI C, it is not possible. There is neither of the functions `setenv` nor `putenv`, and even the [`execv*`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) family of functions is missing.

Instead, I suggest that you write a little interface in the way you want (which possibly looks like `execve`) and is system-dependent. That way, you can change the wrapper easily when you port your program to a non-Windows environment.

Comment: Visual C++ has `_execve` (with a leading underscore), but it's certainly not ANSI C.

Comment: It is not possible to do in pure ANSI C, OK. Can you please tell me how can I do it using Windows API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) function from WInAPI to start a new process

Answer (score 0):

To launch a process using Win32 API use the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function as stated by kayrick.

To set an enviorment you can use [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206%28VS.85%29.aspx).
These are both Win32 API.

You may also want to have a look at [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Hope this helps.